Did Miss Nestoroff plan her own death?
I just finished "Quaderni di Serafino Gubbio, operatore" (Shoot!, The Notebooks of Serafino Gubbio, Cinematograph Operator) by Pirandello.
I was wondering: did Miss Nestoroff plan her own death, or did the plan to humiliate Mister Nuti simply backfired?
